# Java UIMA: Regex Variable inside Regex Variable?

Tags: regex, uima

I am working with RegEx Annotator in UIMA. I know that I can create regex variable in the XML Descriptor file like this:

```
<variables>
    <variable name="month" value="(Jan|Feb|March)" />
</variables>
```

and access it like this in the rule:

```
<rules>
    <rule regEx="Month: \v{month}" />
</rules>
```

which would match `Month: Jan` and `Month: Feb` and `Month: Mar`.

Now I want to use the variable inside another variable, is that possible?
I am looking for something like this:

```
<variables>
    <variable name="monthmonth" value="\v{month}\v{month}" />
</variables>
```

which I want to create appropriate rule to match `Month: JanJan` for example.

I have read the documentation in http://uima.apache.org/downloads/sandbox/RegexAnnotatorUserGuide/RegexAnnotatorUserGuide.html#sandbox.regexAnnotator.conceptsFile.regexVariables and it does not mention about the possibility of using regex variable inside variable, although it does say about `The variables can be used in all concept definition within the same file.`

I am using UIMA RegularExpressionAnnotator 2.3.1.

Any help is appreciated. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs,

> The regex variable name can contain any of the following characters `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`. Other characters are not allowed.

If that's the only restriction, `123` would be a valid name, which you would refer to as `value="\v{123}"`.  How is the parser supposed to know you mean the rule named "123" and not one hundred and twenty-three vertical tab characters?

In most languages (including XML), names can't start with digits.  If that were the case here, it would be possible to embed variable names in variable definitions, because `\v{month}` or `\v{_123}` is guaranteed to be invalid in a Java regex.  (Other regex flavors are more liberal; they would interpret the braces as literal brace characters because `{month}` and `{_123}` can't be interpreted as range expressions.)

The only way to know for sure is to test it.  It sounds like a nice feature to me; if it's not supported, maybe you should request it.

Comment: I was asking this comment because I tried and it just interpreted the value of variable `\v{monthmonth}` literally, which means it would attempt to evaluate `\v{month}\v{month}` as a regex, for which it returns error.

How can I request for this feature to UIMA?

And thanks for your reply, I didn't think that we can infer something from the restriction of variable names. You are quite pro =D

Comment: The project's [web site](http://uima.apache.org/) appears to offer the usual links to issue trackers, discussion forums, etc..  Who knows, you might even find someone there who actually knows something. ;)

Comment: ...as opposed to someone like me, making wild-ass guesses after 30 seconds spent skimming the docs.  (Not sure it came across that way in the original comment.)